# Changing JButton Text or color without final?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, final

Hey all I can change the text of 1 single button easily with "final" but I need to create lots of buttons for a flight booking system, and when the buttons are more, final doesnt work ...

```
JButton btnBookFlight;

eco = new EconomyClass();
eco.setSeats(5);
for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
    btnBookFlight = new JButton("Book" +i);
    btnBookFlight.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            btnBookFlight.setBackground(Color.RED);
            btnBookFlight.setOpaque(true);
            btnBookFlight.setText("Clicked");
        }
    });
    btnBookFlight.setBounds(77, 351, 100, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnBookFlight);
}
```

I would be glad if you can suggest me any trick to get over this.I want to change a buttons color or text when it is clicked or maybe some other cool effects when mouse over but for now only text or color will be enough =).Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the source of the `ActionEvent` in the `ActionListener`

```
btnBookFlight.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

      JButton button = (JButton)event.getSource();
      button.setBackground(Color.RED);
      ...
    }
});
```

`btnBookFlight` has to be `final` for the inner class (`ActionListener`) to access it.

From [JLS 8.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)

> Any local variable, formal parameter, or exception parameter used but not declared in an inner class must be declared final.

If this is not permitted, then the `JButton` may be accessed using the source component of the `ActionEvent` itself using [getSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29).

However, that said, the simplest solution would be to move the `JButton` declaration within the scope of the `for` loop and make it `final`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    final JButton btnBookFlight = new JButton("Book" + i);
    btnBookFlight.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            btnBookFlight.setBackground(Color.RED);
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: +1 For illustrating how to dynamically find the source of an event.

Comment: I will always use this way from now on but can you also please explain the logic behind?

Comment: @Anarkie I wonder why you dont move the button within the `for` loop? See update :)

Comment: Hahahaha good point!This also worked makes things much simpler, I am new to swing actually java as well... So I am using helper plugins like Window Builder or modifying the examples I find on the internet to get what I want, and I think when I tried it first in the `for` loop I had some errors and moved it outside... or in the version I had it was outside.But now also works inside :) thanks again!I owe you =)

Answer (score 1):

Just avoid using anonymous classes for your action listener and the `final` constraint will disappear.

What I mean is use:

```
class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JButton src = (JButton)e.getSource();
    // do what you want

  }
}
```

Comment: in this case avoiding anonymous class you have to check if `instanceof JButton`